# MPLABX syntax cheker errors in ASM mixed with C

Tags: pic, assembly, mplabx, xc8

I'm using XC8 for a project in MPALBX using a PIC18F26K80 and I'm getting lots of `Unable to resolve Identifier` errors in the editor:

[image: ASM Syntax errors in MPLABX]

The code works compiles an runs correctly but the syntax checker in the editor is driving me crazy, highlighting every line in assembler with these errors.

I tried a bunch of things that seemed to make it better, like using `_asm` right after the `#asm` directive, but it always creates some other kind of error instead.

Is there a setting I'm missing or is this just a sorry state of affairs and I have to live with it?

Comment: Does it compile ok? There are known errors with the syntax checker in the IDE. [They have been around for a while](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m668463.aspx).

Comment: As @Roger said, if it compiles OK, don't worry about it. The MPLAB X parser isn't that great. I don't think there's anything you can do about it..

Answer (score 2):

MPLAB X has always had problems with the parser. If the code complies just ignore them. You didn't mention what version you are using but I've found that since version 3 the parser got much better.

Comment: Everything compiles just fine, so it looks like I'll have to live with these errors. I'd rather the parser just ignore the `#asm` sections rather than try to analyse their syntax using the wrong assumptions.